# Reading locale settings from shared preferences doesn't work for the MainActivity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am changing Locale settings inside my app with this method:

```
public void setLanguageSettings(String localeLang){
    Locale locale = new Locale(localeLang);
    saveString("lang", localeLang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration configSlo = new Configuration();
    configSlo.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configSlo, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

As you can see, the localeLang String variable is then saved to SharedPreferences. This variable is in my case either `"sl"` or `"en"` (default is `"en"`).

Then I'm calling this (same) method everytime the application starts (every time MainActivity is opened):

```
String language = getString("lang");
setLanguageSettings(language);
```

The Locale is changed successfully (I checked with log) but the problem is that the change can't be seen in the MainActivity. If I open any other activity, the language is correct, but the MainActivity remains `"en"` even tho it is supposed to be `"sl"`. I'd have to restart MainActivity for it to be `"sl"`.

Comment: you have to check that it at the app start and in your activity called it in onResume() method...........

Comment: I added onResume and this code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: But after change your language you have to check local from shared preference that if it is "sl" then return true otherwise false means returns english lang..

Comment: Could you maybe show me some code for example? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question in a weird way. I just called setContentView again in the change language method:

```
setContentView(R.Layout.MainLayout);
```